# Store field data as a json array php

Tags: php, json, laravel

I would like to store a json array into the database from user input.  However, I'm not getting the desired result.  Below is the code:

The HTML/View

```
<div class="form-group" id="InputsWrapper" {{$errors->has('qualification') ? 'has-error': ''}}>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="qualification[]" id="field_1" value=""><a href="#" class="removeclass"></a> @if($errors->has('qualification'))
        <span class="help-block">{{$errors->first('first')}}</span> @endif
    </div>
</div>
<div id="AddMoreFileId">
    <a href="#" id="AddMoreFileBox" class="btn btn-info ">Add field</a>
    <br>
    <br>
</div>
```

THE CONTROLLER

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    $request->validate([
        'qualpurpose' => 'required',

    ]);


    $qualpurpose = Qualpurpose::create([
        'qualpurpose' => $request->input('qualpurpose'),

        'qualification' => json_encode($request->input('qualification')),
        'qualificationheader_id'=>session()->get('key')

    ]);


    if ($qualpurpose) {

        return redirect()->route('qualpurposes.show', ['qualpurpose' => $qualpurpose->id])
            ->with('success', 'Purpose created Successfully');
    }


    return back()->withInput()->with('error' , 'Purpose could not be created');
}
```

I was expecting the input to get stored in the following format:

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

But Instead I get

```
["adfadsf","bgadf qwe asd","adfadsf ase asdf asder","adfadsf qwer","asdf ffase weww","qwess cfesdf"]
```

'[' Square brackets instead of normal curly bracket. Is there a way I can ensure that the data gets stored as normal json array and not with square brackets ?

Comment: Square brackets indicate an array. Curly brackets indicate an object. This is still valid json.

Comment: The problem I am getting with [ square brackets is that when I wanna display the data on the view, I get all sorts of errors like index is incorrect.  This makes it very difficult for me

Comment: You may want to rethink how you're creating the array before you encode it, then. The array it's storing has no associated indexes, just the default number indexes (0,1,2,3). You can tell because there are no keys showing in the encoded array.

Comment: @aynber, do you possibly have any suggestions on how could store this data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php you can use `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`

```
json_encode($request->input('qualification'), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
    'qualification' => json_encode($request->input('qualification')),
```

To

```
    'qualification' => json_encode($request->input('qualification'), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT),
```

see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for more information